# How to determine whether dotnet and VSTORuntime is installed in WIX Bootstrapper

Tags: wix, bootstrapper, wix3.7

i made a setup file of my Add-Ins project using wix. it has some dependencies like dotNet and VSTO Runtime. so I used Wix bootstrapper to confirm that dependencies must be installed before installing the product it works too. But i need conditional installation of dependencies like if dotNet and VSTO runtime is installed then don't look for install these items. i tried the registry searches too but didn't get success, here is my bootstrapper code tell me where i need to modify my code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi" xmlns:bal="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/BalExtension" 
     xmlns:util="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/UtilExtension">
    <Bundle Name="FinalSetup" Version="1.0.0.0" Manufacturer="Ramesh" UpgradeCode="5704ca64-b7bc-487b-8867-cabb51621c0e">
    <BootstrapperApplicationRef Id="WixStandardBootstrapperApplication.RtfLicense" >
      <bal:WixStandardBootstrapperApplication LicenseFile="mylicense.rtf"
                                              SuppressOptionsUI="yes" />
    </BootstrapperApplicationRef>

        <Chain>
      <ExePackage Id="dotNetFx40_Full_x86_x64" SourceFile="dotNetFx40_Full_x86_x64.exe" PerMachine="yes" Cache="no"
                  Compressed="no"
                  DownloadUrl="http://download.microsoft.com/download/9/5/A/95A9616B-7A37-4AF6-BC36-D6EA96C8DAAE/dotNetFx40_Full_x86_x64.exe"
                  Permanent="yes"
                  InstallCommand="/q /norestart"
                  DetectCondition="VSTOR40_Installed"
                  InstallCondition="1" />
      <ExePackage Id="VSTORuntime" SourceFile="vstor_redist.exe" Permanent="yes" Vital="yes" Cache="no" Compressed="no"
                  DownloadUrl="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=158917"
                  PerMachine="yes"
                  InstallCommand="/q /norestart"
                  DetectCondition="VSTOR40_Installed"
                  InstallCondition="NOT VSTOR40_Installed" />
      <MsiPackage SourceFile="$(var.Setup.TargetPath)" Vital="yes" Compressed="yes" Id="WordAddIns" After="VSTORuntime"/>
    </Chain>
    </Bundle>
</Wix>
```

Another issue i have is, i attached the `mylicense.rft` which has some dummy contents. but setup doesn't show the license content during installation process, look at the attached snapshot
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue was I forget to use value attribute which causes this problem. This was problem with `rtf` file, after changing the file it worked as expected.
Here is the working version of code.

Working version is here

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi" xmlns:bal="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/BalExtension" 
     xmlns:util="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/UtilExtension">
  <Bundle Name="FinalSetup" Version="1.0.0.0" Manufacturer="Ramesh" UpgradeCode="5704ca64-b7bc-487b-8867-cabb51621c0e">
    <BootstrapperApplicationRef Id="WixStandardBootstrapperApplication.RtfLicense" >
      <bal:WixStandardBootstrapperApplication LicenseFile="mylicense.rtf"
                                              SuppressOptionsUI="yes" />
    </BootstrapperApplicationRef>
    <util:RegistrySearch Id="VSTORuntimeTest" Root="HKLM" Key="SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VSTO Runtime Setup\v4R\" Value="VSTORFeature_CLR40" Variable="VSTORFeature"/>
    <util:RegistrySearch Id="VSTORuntimeVersionV4R" Root="HKLM" Key="SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VSTO Runtime Setup\v4R\" Value="Version" Variable="VSTORVersionV4R"/>
    <util:RegistrySearch Id="VSTORuntimeVersionV4" Root="HKLM" Key="SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VSTO Runtime Setup\v4\" Value="Version" Variable="VSTORVersionV4"/>

    <util:RegistrySearch Id="DotNetTest" Root="HKLM" Key="SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Net Framework Setup\NDP\v4\Full" Value="Install" Variable="DotNetInstall"/>
    <util:RegistrySearch Id="DotNetVersion" Root="HKLM" Key="SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Net Framework Setup\NDP\v4\Full" Value="Version" Variable="DotNetVersion"/>

    <Chain> 
      <ExePackage Id="dotNetFx40_Full_x86_x64" SourceFile="dotNetFx40_Full_x86_x64.exe" PerMachine="yes" Cache="no"
                  Compressed="no"
                  DownloadUrl="http://download.microsoft.com/download/9/5/A/95A9616B-7A37-4AF6-BC36-D6EA96C8DAAE/dotNetFx40_Full_x86_x64.exe"
                  Permanent="yes"
                  InstallCommand="/q /norestart"
                  DetectCondition="NOT DotNetInstall"
                  InstallCondition="NOT DotNetInstall OR NOT (DotNetVersion >=v4.0.30319)" />
      <ExePackage Id="VSTORuntime" SourceFile="vstor_redist.exe" Permanent="yes" Vital="yes" Cache="no" Compressed="no"
                  DownloadUrl="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=158917"
                  PerMachine="yes"
                  InstallCommand="/q /norestart"
                  DetectCondition="VSTORFeature"
                  InstallCondition="NOT VSTORFeature OR NOT (VSTORVersionV4R >=v10.0.40303) OR NOT (VSTORVersionV4 >=v10.0.21022)" />
      <MsiPackage SourceFile="$(var.Setup.TargetPath)" Vital="yes" Compressed="yes" Id="WordAddIns"/>
    </Chain>
  </Bundle>
</Wix>
```

Comment: For the dotnet4 dependency you can actually reference the WixNetFxExtension and include <PackageGroupRef Id="NetFx40Redist" /> in your chain: http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/wixnetfxextension.htm and this will automatically work out whether dotnet4 is installed.

Comment: This saved me days of work. Thank you! I had to enable WixUtilExtension in .wixproj as follows: 

<ItemGroup>

                <WixExtension Include="WixUtilExtension">
   <HintPath>$(WixExtDir)\WixUtilExtension.dll</HintPath>
   <Name>WixUtilExtension</Name>
  </WixExtension>
 </ItemGroup>